# How to show polylines on map

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to show the polylines and it shows the correct line when I put it in `onLocationResult`.

However, I only want it to show polylines when the user clicks on the start button. 
So I tried to put the code into `onClickListener`, the screen only displays the marker but not the lines.

```
Location mLastLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private FirebaseAuth myAuth;
    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private Marker currentUserLocationMarker;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> points; //added
    Polyline line;
    private Button btnStartRun;
    LatLng latLng;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_googls_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        btnStartRun=findViewById(R.id.btnStartRun);

        btnStartRun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                points.add(latLng);//add points to the array
                redrawLine();

                myAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("OnlineUsers");//.child("OnlineUser");
                DatabaseReference currentUserDB=mDatabase.child(myAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                currentUserDB.child("CurrentLatitude").setValue(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
                currentUserDB.child("CurrentLongitude").setValue(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Here is my `onLocationResult`

```
 LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                mLastLocation = location;

                latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));


            }
        }
    };
```

Here is my `redrawline()`

```
    private void redrawLine(){

        mMap.clear();  //clears all Markers and Polylines

        PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);//set the colour and width of the polyline
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            LatLng point = points.get(i);
            options.add(point);
        }
        addMarker(); //add Marker in current position
        line = mMap.addPolyline(options); //add Polyline
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only adding to points on the button click, but that is incorrect.  You should be adding to points every time you get an onLocationChanged (or perhaps your location callback), otherwise, you don't have any line to draw.

Your onLocationChanged (or callback) should call the redrawLine method every time.

Your redrawLine method should have a flag, such as hasStarted.  If hasStarted = false, then clear the map, but don't draw the line.  If hasStarted = true, then clear the map and DO draw the line.

In the onClick listener, simply set hasStarted = true (or, if you want it to be a toggle, say hasStarted = !hasStarted).

Comment: Thank you. I follow what you said but I am not sure why even though I set hasStarted as false at first and added if hasStarted = true, draw the line in the redrawline(), it still draw the routes even though I didn't click on the start button.

Comment: I hope you are using the syntax ... if hasStarted == true and not if hasStarted = true, as the latter will assign true to the hasStarted flag and then evaluate the if statement - so, it will always be true. Where as the former will check for equivalency.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry about this, I am new to programming therefore I didn't know the difference between the 2.